# Node.js async map function ignores async with AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, async-await

I just had two of these issues back to back.  One was with an AWS Lambda function I wrote and one was with deploying to Vercel, which also uses AWS Lambda I believe.

In both cases, running the code locally was fine, but deploying and running with Lambda produced unexplained issues that I eventually tracked down to this:

```
array.map(async () => {
   await ...
})
```

with AWS Lambda, the asynchronous map function doesn't behave asynchronously at all.  Now that I look at it, I must be doing something wrong, but it seems to works asyncrhonously on my local machine.

Comment: Use `for..loop` instead of `.map`

Comment: yes it worked with a map, i found that to be the solution before i made this post. but i am not sure why